# Why are multiple rows not concatenating?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have this data in a single table:

```
ID      ANIMAL
555000  Dog
555000  Cow
555000  Fox
657000  Fox
817900  Dog
817900  Fox
829800  Fox
830300  Fox
830600  Fox
830800  Fox
831100  Dog
831100  Fox
839900  Fox
```

I need to create output that groups by the ID and then creates a delimited string of the Id's animals. Given the data above, I need the following output. Note, each ID should be an individual row in the resultset and the animals should be concatenated into a single string for each ID. I'm not looking to create one large concatenated string.

```
555000  Dog<br/>Cow<br/>Fox
657000  Fox
817900  Dog<br/>Fox
829800  Fox
830300  Fox
830600  Fox
830800  Fox
831100  Dog<br/>Fox
839900  Fox
```

Here is the SQL I have so far. It produces a row for each ID, ANIMAL combination. The problem is the values in ANIMAL field are not being concatenated. What am I doing wrong?

```
select ID,
        REPLACE (wm_concat (DISTINCT ANIMAL),',','<br/>')
from TheTable
group by ID, ANIMAL
```

Comment: Your `group by ID, ANIMAL` ensures that there's only one distinct animal per row. Remove the `ANIMAL` column from the `group by` and it will work.

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley - Yes, that's it. I found my mistake while looking over the wm_concat example at the link posted by gustavodidomenico below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the LISTAGG analytic function:

```
SELECT ID, LISTAGG(ANIMAL, '<br/>') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ANIMAL) animals
FROM   TheTable
GROUP BY ID;
```

Note: You will be limited to 4000 **bytes**.

Edit:

There is a good resource for string aggregation techniques:

https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques#user_defined_aggregate_function

Comment: Sensible advice - however, one should keep in mind that LISTAGG fails utterly if the concatenated string becomes too long (> 4000 characters).

Comment: @FrankSchmitt, thats new for me. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: That's what I'm encountering now but I don't see how we can be anywhere close to 4000 characters...

Comment: @DenaliHardtail I am a little bit confused now. Did it work? Or you are concerned about the 4k chars?

Comment: @gustavodidomenico - Sorry. It did not work due to "ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long". This is just not possible as the ID is, at most, 10 characters and the animal is around 20 with four animals, at most, needed to be concatenating into a field for a row. Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: `LISTAGG` doesn't support `DISTINCT` so your string probably has a zillion dogs and cats instead of just one of each.

Comment: @DenaliHardtail,  after a research a I found an useful link with some techniques.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use `XMLAGG / XMLELEMENT` instead of `LISTAGG` (this will avoid the dreaded ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long):

```
select ID, 
  RTRIM(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(E,
                          t.animal || ',')).EXTRACT('//text()').getclobval(),
        ',') as animals
from theTable t
group by ID
```

This

- converts each animal into a XML node (using `XMLELEMENT`)
- aggregates the XML elements using `XMLAGG` and the string concatenation operator `||`
- gets rid of the XML stuff using `EXTRACT` and `getClobVal()`
- removes the trailing comma with `RTRIM`

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7db59d16c/4431)

IIRC there's a slightly more elegant way using `XMLCAST` instead of `EXTRACT` / `getClobVal`, but I can`t access my codebase right now to check it.